# Loop until an input is of a specific type

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a program that repeatedly asks an user for an input until the input is of a specific type. My code:

```
value = input("Please enter the value")

while isinstance(value, int) == False:
     print ("Invalid value.")
     value = input("Please enter the value")
     if isinstance(value, int) == True:
         break
```

Based on my understanding of python, the line

```
if isintance(value, int) == True
    break
```

should end the while loop if **value** is an integer, but it doesn't.

My question is: 
a) How would I make a code that would ask the user for an input, until the input is an integer? 
b) Why doesn't my code work?

Comment: `input` always return string object (`str`).

Comment: probably want value.isdigit()

Comment: and `<boolean> == False` is never ok :-). Always just `not <boolean>`

Comment: what! input return int if given. try input()+1 and give 2 as input/

Comment: In Python3, `input()` returns string. And in Py2, `input()` is the same as `eval(input())` in Py3

Comment: aha sorry didnt see python-3.x tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work is because `input()` will always return a string. Which will always cause `isinstance(value, int)` to always evaluate to `False`.

You probably want:

```
value = ''
while not value.strip().isdigit():
     value = input("Please enter the value")
```

Comment: Also, you may want `value.strip().isdigit()`

Answer (score 1):

Be aware when using `.isdigit()`, it will return False on negative integers. So `isinstance(value, int)` is maybe a better choice.

I cannot comment on accepted answer because of low rep.

Answer (score 0):

`input` always returns a string, you have to convert it to `int` yourself.

Try this snippet:

```
while True:
    try:
        value = int(input("Please enter the value: "))
    except ValueError:
        print ("Invalid value.")
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manage negative integers you should use :

```
value = ''
while not value.strip().lstrip("-").isdigit():
    value = input("Please enter the value")
```